# Print top 100 lines to a file

Tags: bash

Is it possible to write the top 100 lines of a file to another file in bash? I know you can use:

```
echo "thing to print" >> file.txt
```

But what if you want to do something like:

```
echo head -100 file1.txt >> file2.txt
```

I've tried this and it literally just prints this to file2.txt:

> echo head -100 file1.txt >> file2.txt

Tried looking around SO but couldn't see anything that quite did this.

Comment: `head -100 file1.txt > file2.txt`, or if you prefer, `>>` for appending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `head` as a command, not an argument to `echo`:

```
head -100 file1.txt >>file2.txt
```